# Given $\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} < 2$, what is range for $x$?

Tags: inequality

$\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} < 2$

$ x \neq 1$

$\sqrt{2-x} > 0$

$ x < 2$

$3\sqrt{2-x} < 2x - 2$

$3\sqrt{2-x} - 2x + 2 < 0$

what do you think i should proceed next,

without derivative?

Comment: Go back one step, to $3 \sqrt{2-x}< 2x -2$. One important observation: The left-hand side must be non-negative, so therefore the right-hand side must also be non-negative. So that's one condition. Once you have applied this, you can square both sides and continue from there.

Comment: try $u=\sqrt{2-x}$ , then $2x-2 = -2(2-x)+2 = -2u^2+2$

Comment: By squaring, $0< 4x^2 + x - 14$ ?

Comment: $3u < -2{u}^2 + 2$ then $2u^2 + 3u -2 < 0$ $(2u - 1)(u + 2) = 0$ then $x = 7/4$

Answer (score 1):

In other words, solve it for $x$:
$$\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} < 2 \Rightarrow \\ 
\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} - 2<0 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}-2x+2}{x-1} < 0 \\
3\sqrt{2-x}-2x+2=0 \Rightarrow \\9(2-x)=4x^2-8x+4 \Rightarrow \\4x^2+x-14=0 \Rightarrow \\x_1=\require{cancel}\cancel{-2},x_2=\frac74$$
The critical values are $1,\frac74$. Check the signs of the three intervals:
$$x=0<1 \Rightarrow \frac{3\sqrt{2}+2}{-1}<0 \quad \checkmark\\
1<x=1.64<\frac74 \Rightarrow \frac{3\cdot 0.6-1.28}{0.64}\not<0\\
\frac74<x=1.84\le 2 \Rightarrow \frac{3\cdot 0.4-1.68}{0.84}<0 \quad \checkmark$$
Hence:
$$x\in (-\infty,1)\cup \left(\frac74,2\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $x\leq2$ and $x\neq1.$

Let $2-x=t^2,$ where $t\geq0.$

Thus, $$\frac{3t}{2-t^2-1}<2$$ or
$$\frac{2t^2+3t-2}{1-t^2}<0$$ or
$$\frac{(2t-1)(t+2)}{(t-1)(t+1)}>0$$ or
$$t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup(1,+\infty).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: is it x > 7/4 ?

Comment: Or $x<1$. There are two cases.

Comment: Not x> 7/4. 7/4<x<2 right?

Comment: Or $x<1$. There are two cases. With the domain, of course: $x\leq2$

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated, $\dfrac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}  $ is defined only when $x\ne1$ (because of the denominator)

and $x<2$ (because of the numerator).

When $x<1$, $\dfrac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1}  <0<2.$

When $x>1$, $\dfrac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} <2\iff3\sqrt{2-x}<2x-2\iff9(2-x)<4x^2-8x+4$

$\iff0<4x^2+x-14=(4x-7)(x+2)\iff x>\frac74.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x-1<0$ satisfies the inequality $\frac{3\sqrt{2-x}}{x-1} < 2$ automatically. So, one solution is $x<1$.

On the other hand, if $x-1>0$, rewrite the inequality as you did,

$$3\sqrt{2-x}<2(x-1)\implies 2(2-x)+3\sqrt{2-x}-2<0$$

Then, factorize,

$$(2\sqrt{2-x}-1)(\sqrt{2-x}+2)<0$$

which leads to $2\sqrt{2-x}-1<0$ and the second solution $\frac74<x\le 2$. Thus, the full range is

$$x\in(-\infty, 1) \cup (\frac74,2]$$

Comment: how to factorize and get $(2\sqrt{2-x}-1)(\sqrt{2-x}+2)<0$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter - note $2(2-x)+3\sqrt{2-x}-2$!is quadratic in $\sqrt{2-x}=t$, i.e. $2t^2+3t-2=(2t-1)(t+2)$